# Markdown styles not getting loaded in Nuxt + Vue project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown, tailwind-css, javascript-marked

I am working on a Vue + Nuxt + Tailwind project and using the [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) library to convert a text into markdown.

The issue is that some styles like "Headings" and "Link" are loading properly, while some basic styles like "bold", "italics" are working fine.

For example:

- When I use "*hello* world", it gets converted to "*hello* world".
- When I use "# hello world", it does not increase the size of the text.
- When I use "[google](https://google.com)", it does create a link, but the link is not blue colored.

Not sure what the issue is here. If any more details are required, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this was using Tailwind CSS's [typography](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography) plugin.

### Here are the steps to be followed:

Install the plugin first.

#### Using npm

`npm install @tailwindcss/typography`

#### Using Yarn

`yarn add @tailwindcss/typography`.

Then add the plugin to your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Then add the `prose` class to the element where you are displaying the markdown.

`<div class="prose" v-html="cleanedMarkdown"></div>`.

This provided the needed formatting for the markdown.

Comment: This is great thanks!

Comment: I was fighting this issue for hours. Thanks for the comment, man. I can add this documentation resources in addition to the github link you provided: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the tailwind.css
in tailwind, h1 - h6 headers dont work.

Option 1)
add this to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
....
}
```

source :https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1460

Option 2)Try adding custom css for `h1`..`h6` in your `css` file.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp *copy the styles from here*

Similarly try add custom css for other issues.

Comment: Option 1 wont work because it will remove all the core plugins..

Comment: If u inspect your markdown output, the link wont be blue because of the same reason..

Comment: for  a `link`
```css
a:link {
    color: blue !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaartik. Adding custom CSS works, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this. For example, lists also don't work here.